# Is it correct to use 'have had + verb (past participle)'?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-tense, active-vs-passive

*A reward has been announced for the employees who **have worked** or **have had worked** hard.*

As far as I understand this is an example of present perfect tense. Here, **have** is an auxiliary verb and it will be followed by a past participle verb. So **have worked** is grammatically correct in my opinion.

Could anyone please tell me if 'have had + verb (past participle)' is grammatically correct in any case.

Comment: Do you have a name for the tense you're asking about? I only know present perfect (have worked) and past perfect (had worked). What tense is _have had worked_? Are you sure it exists?

Comment: @BenA. No, I'm not sure of its existence. But I watched a TV serial called 'Big Bang Theory' and I saw the characters there using 'had have had brought' in their conversation. Here is the YouTube link of that conversation: https://youtu.be/NiylEdcIZ2Q

Comment: It's comedy. They're talking about time travels and inventing grammatical tenses. Those are not used in our time and space.

Comment: @BenA. That’s a relief!